# Request Azure Databricks Access Token using Powershell instead of Bash

Tags: azure, powershell, databricks

I run the following code in Bash and I successfully receive an Azure Databricks access token from AAD.

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_id>/oauth2/v2.0/token \
-d 'client_id=<app_id>' \
-d 'grant_type=client_credentials' \
-d 'scope=2ff814a6-3304-4ab8-85cb-cd0e6f879c1d%2F.default' \
-d 'client_secret=<app_secret>'
```

I am trying to adapt this to PowerShell, which is more relevant to my use case. My equivalent PowerShell script is :

```
$headers = @{'Content-Type'='application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
$method = 'POST'
$url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_id>/oauth2/v2.0/token'
$body = @{'client_id'='<app_id>'; 'grant_type'='client_credentials'; 'scope'='2ff814a6-3304-4ab8-85cb-cd0e6f879c1d%2F.default'; 'client_secret'='<app_secret>'}

Invoke-WebRequest $url -Method $method -Headers $headers -Body $body
```

When I run the PowerShell script only, I receive an error stating "The provided value for scope 2ff814a6-3304-4ab8-85cb-cd0e6f879c1d%2F.default is not valid. Client credential flows must have a scope value with /.default suffixed to the resource identifier". The url encoded scope I am sending to the api is clearly suffixed with '.default', so I am not sure what the problem is... Any idea what could be contributing to this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce in my environment and got the same error like below:***

[image]

To resolve the error, make sure to pass the scope as `2ff814a6-3304-4ab8-85cb-cd0e6f879c1d/.default` like below:

```
$headers = @{'Content-Type'='application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
$method = 'POST'
$url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/1810a95e-99f3-46e0-84e8-8axxxx30/oauth2/v2.0/token'
$body = @{'client_id'='52254c1f-d4a1-454d-bc37-d66xxxxe'; 'grant_type'='client_credentials'; 'scope'='2ff814a6-3304-4ab8-85cb-cd0e6f879c1d/.default'; 'client_secret'='jFv8Q~QscXf~7ANRVrv9qLx118CJlrowvxxxx'}

Invoke-WebRequest $url -Method $method -Headers $headers -Body $body
```

The access token got generated successfully like below:

[image]